# Media Query Set to 480px but behaving as if it's 320px (iPhone4)

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, media-queries, viewport

I have a demo of my problem setup here:
http://chevasdesign.com/storage/index.php

The viewport is currently set without a scaling attribute (because having it prevents the page from scaling between landscape and portrait)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

At the end of my CSS I have the following media query in my CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    #wide { width: 440px; }
}
```

`#wide` has a width of 920px, a margin of 20px on the left and right, and a gray background. It happens to be the only element.

When I load the page in portrait or landscape on the iPhone4 (in my case), the div spans horizontally beyond the width of the screen requiring horizontal scrolling. See image: http://chevasdesign.com/storage/viewport-media-queries-problem.png).

Shouldn't the iPhone scale the page so that anything less than 480px wide will fit on the screen?

When I set `#wide` to 280px wide, inside of the media query (which totals 320px with margins), the div fits on the screen, even though the media query has the device width set to 480px. What am I missing?

What is strange to me is that I have the exact viewport setting and media query settings on a full blown website in WordPress and all the media queries are working as intended.

Comment: changing the viewport to "width=device-height" fixed my issue. I understand now that since the device is 480px, I am defaulting the content width to that value. I still don't understand why width=device-width works perfectly on WordPress websites (even themes I wrote from scratch), but when I'm writing free form HTML, it behaves as I described above.

Comment: Fixed: I understand now that since the device **height** is 480px, I am defaulting the content width to that value.